# trying to run several commands in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running a `.bat` file on my windows pc.
what I am trying to do is have several commands run when `.bat` file opens.
I also want enable the cmd prompt window to stay open when the `.bat` file is run.

In order to keep the `.bat` open when I used `cmd /k` at the start of my `.bat` file.
this seem to enable the window to stay open. Then I want to run my commands, however, the first command is the only one that seems to run. my set up is as follows:

```
cmd /k
echo a
echo b 
echo c
```

the cmd prints `a` no problem but does not print the others.
i have tried adding `&` and `&&` to no avail.

I am creating my `.bat` from a `.txt` file and saving it with the `.bat` extension.
any ideas how i can get the remaining `echo b` and `echo c` commands to run?

Comment: `cmd /K` in your batch file opens another `cmd.exe` instance, but the remaining code of your script is not executed in that new instance but in the one the batch file runs in; type `exit` to terminate the new instance, then the remaining code will run (append `pause` as the last command in case you run the batch file by double-clicking its icon)…

Comment: thanks for having a look.  so are you saying my `.bat` file code should be: `cmd /k  echo a echo b echo c pause exit`?

Comment: No, I meant to manually type `exit` into Command Prompt upon starting your batch file, and afterwards, the `echo` commands will execute; a `pause` as the last command of the batch file would just prevent the console window to close before you have a chance to review the output…

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the order?

```
@Echo a
@Echo b
@Echo c
@%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K
```

…which in your less robust syntax, would look like this:

```
echo a
echo b
echo c
cmd /k
```